# Deprecate, not delete, old addresses in Google Contacts

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Contacts sometimes sign up for a new email address. That doesn't mean that emails they sent to me from an old address are no longer from that contact. It just means they don't use that address any more.

I want to keep those old addresses associated with a contact. I just don't want to accidentally send emails to the old address because Gmail autofilled it in.

Is there *any* way to deprecate an old e-mail address so Gmail stops autofilling it in the To: box, but still knows that emails from that address came from that person?

Comment: If the different email addresses are not merged into a single contact you can add `(depracated)` to the contact name associated with the old address to help you avoid emailing that address

Answer (score 5):

I put quotation marks around the deprecated email addresses. This doesn't prevent Google from autofilling them in the `To:` box but you can easily spot and avoid them.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no way to include an email address as an email address without having it appear as an option when addressing a message.

You can move the email address to the "Notes" field, so you'll be able to search for that address and still find the person.

Probably more practical is to change the order of the email addresses on the contact so that the active ones are at the top and the inactive ones are at the bottom. That's the order they'll appear in the drop-down.

Comment: The order of emails is also important if that contact is part of an email group. Gmail appears to pick the first email address when emailing to the group. Personally, I move out of date email addresses to the "Notes" field so I don't accidentally use that address again in the future.